# PHP Randomly Generated Photo to Display on HTML Doc

Tags: php, html

I've been messing with this issue all day and I'm close to solving it. I have a .php file that reads an image directory and picks an image at random to display (and it works properly if I navigate to the file in the web address mysite.com/images.php). The issue I'm having is taking that randomly generated image and putting it into a regular HTML webpage.

Php code in images.php for reference:

```
<?php
   $imagesDir = 'images/';
   $images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
   $randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
   echo "<img src='$randomImage'>";
?>
```

Comment: maybe if you marked your other questions as solved, given if they were?

Comment: So far no one has solved my original question; they have only given me further insight into the issue and clues as to how to solve it (which I am thankful for). Once it is finally solved, I plan on updating the last two questions with a brutally detailed answer for other people who are not coding experts!

Comment: The code looks fine. What is the output of the file from the server when you look at the source code in a browser? Is $randomImage visible as a valid URL in the HTML?

Comment: @fred2 I was a bit confused by your question. When I load "mysite.com/images.php" the source code just lists the original file name of the randomly chosen image file. I also tried mysite.com/$randomImage and mysite.com/$randomImage.jpg with only 404 response pages showing. If you are referring to the original webpage, I had the code written as: <img src="images.php"> and I tried <img src="images.php/$randomImage"> in case that's what you meant (with no success).

Comment: What I am trying to judge is whether the code outputs a valid URL for the random image or not. So does the output HTML read something like `<img src="images/someimage.jpg">`? Is that a valid relative path to the images on your server, relative to the PHP file? If in doubt, use an absolute URL instead, eg `<img src="http://example.com/images/someimage.jpg">`

Comment: PS: @bardizba's answer simply uses a different (and unnecessarily resource intensive) way to output the image. There's absolutely no logic to doing it that way in this context when you are just generating simple HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

images.php :

```
<?php
$imagesDir = __DIR__ . '/4611416038/';
$images    = glob($imagesDir . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];

//Output
$data = file_get_contents($randomImage);
ob_clean();
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); //Make browser recorgnize it as image
echo $data;
?>
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="images.php" alt="random-image"/>
</body>
</html>
```

the images.php will give ouput as image to the browser. it should works

Comment: Hey I just gave that a try and it is not working. When i view the homepage there is a icon of a torn photo with the alt tag text displaying next to it. If I visit the .php page I get a page of glyphs like this "�  A l � � �!!H" (not sure if that helps or not!). I edited your code so the $imagesDir was what I had before with no success. Any ideas on something to try next?